# ban the [limit] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As I expected, the tag [limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) has 0 subscribers, likely because it does not make a lot of sense... it is too general. Can we just ban it.

Answer (score 1):

What? The tag is perfectly cromulent. A *limit* is traditional unix terminology for imposing that a program uses a maximum amount of a certain resource (memory, CPU time, open files, etc.), as in the Csh `limit` command, the Bourne shell `ulimit` command, the `setrlimit` system call.

That the tag has no subscriber is irrelevant. This is not a subject in which there is much focused expertise — you don't see many people who are an expert in limits, like there are OpenBSD experts and Gnome experts and so on — so it is natural that the tag has no subscriber. However, the tag has an unambiguous meaning and is useful in searches. There's absolutely no reason to ban that tag.

Comment: It would be more acceptable to me if the tag was only used in the case of the `limit` command you mention, and nowhere else.

Comment: @Tshepang That doesn't make any sense. There are extremely few questions (probably none yet) about the `limit` csh builtin. There's a [tag:ulimit] tag for the corresponding Bourne shell builtin. [tag:limit] is more general, and makes more sense as a result: it's about what you're trying to achieve and not the precise way to do it. You haven't explained why you think the tag is unacceptable. Why do you object to it (other than its having no subscriber, which as I said is not a valid objection)?

Comment: I just think it is too general (not specific enough). I had a look at [the tag at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limit) for comparison, and though it has over 1000 questions, it only has 4 subscribers. That's how uninteresting it is.

Comment: I just think that a good tag is one where a bunch of people would think *that's an interesting one to subscribe to*. How many people would say they are interested in **limits**? Limits of what?

Comment: @Tshepang Again, that's not the only use of tags. They are also useful when searching questions. Besides, someone might subscribe to the tag, say the author of a CPU or bandwidth throttling tool.

Comment: That someone is going to get questions unrelated to subject of interest since `limits` is pretty much vague. For example, look at the number of questions unrelated to CPUs on that tag. Also, if used for searching, surely the word *limit* will be in the text, so the post should show up in results.